# Jupyter crashes while deleting many rows from Panda data series

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm using Jupyter notebook locally on Windows 10 to have a Pandas dataframe called pop_data composed of 4 columns and over 450,000 rows. I'm trying to remove about 400,000 rows from it (with indexes of the rows to be deleted coming from a list called deleteTimes).

```
for IndexOfRowToDelete in deleteTimes:
    pop_data= pop_data.drop([pop_data.index[IndexOfRowToDelete]])
```

This continually returns a 302 GET error in the CMD line, and breaks Jupyter for me (executing commands in Jupyter after this won't work anymore- I have to restart the notebook). I'm wondering if this issue comes up because the size of the operation that I'm trying to perform is too big? I haven't found anything in the documentation that says this would be the case, but it would make sense.

Does anyone know the cause of it? Is there any way that I can get around the issue, and remove all the 400,000 rows without breaking Jupyter?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your `for` loop with one liner:

```py
pop_data= pop_data.drop(pop_data.index[deleteTimes], axis=0)
```

Alternatively, since you know you are removing ca 90% of the dataframe, you can revert the process, and re-assign the rows you want to keep to the dataframe i.e.

```py
pop_data=pop_data.loc[pop_data.index[[el for el in range(len(pop_data.index)) if el not in deleteTime]]]
```